# Display last working day if not Saturday or Sunday for 12 months

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble getting the last working day of the month to dispaly for 12 months and display the last working day of the month (not a weekend), if I just display one month using:

echo date('l', strtotime($lastworkingday))." ".$lastworkingday;

it works, but I can only get the 12 months to display for 12 month using I can't workout how to get it working. It only works for 12 month using the below.

echo $lastworkingday->format('t-m-Y') . " | ";

The problem is it shows the last working day of the month even if it is a weekend. Where am I going wrong please.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use DateTime;
use DatePeriod;
use DateInterval;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ExportCalendarPayments extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'calendar:payments';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Exports Payment Calendar Spreadsheet';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

         //Create an instance of now
        $now = new \DateTime( '01-01-2021', new \DateTimeZone( 'Europe/London' ) );


       //sets the absolute last day of the month based off $now
        $lastdateofthemonth = new \DateTime( $now->format("t-m-Y"), new \DateTimeZone(      'Europe/London' ) );
        $lastdateofthemonth->add(new \DateInterval('P11M'));
 




        $lastdateofthemonth = date("31-07-2021");


        $lastworkingday = date('l', strtotime($lastdateofthemonth));

        if($lastworkingday == "Saturday") { 
        $newdate = strtotime ('-1 day', strtotime($lastdateofthemonth));
        $lastworkingday = date ('j-m-Y', $newdate);
        }
        elseif($lastworkingday == "Sunday") { 
        $newdate = strtotime ('-2 day', strtotime($lastdateofthemonth));
        $lastworkingday = date ( 'j-m-Y' , $newdate );
        }

    /*This output correct date, but I can't get it to show for each of the 12 months*/    echo date('l', strtotime($lastworkingday))." ".$lastworkingday;




 
   //Define our interval (12months)
        $interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');

        //testing date interval setup
        //echo $interval->format('%d days');

        //Setup a DatePeriod instance to iterate between the start and end date by the interval
        $period = new \DatePeriod( $now, $interval, $lastworkingday );

                //Iterate over the DatePeriod instance
        foreach( $period as $lastworkingday ){
            //Make sure the day displayed is greater than or equal to todayy.
            //if( ){
             /*echo $lastworkingday->format( 't-m-Y' ) . " | "; */
              echo $lastworkingday->format('t-m-Y') . " | "; 
           /*   echo date('l', strtotime($lastworkingday))." ".$lastworkingday;*/
            //}
        } 


        //

       $data_array = array (
            array ('1','2','2'),
            array ('2','2','2'),
            array ('3','6','2'),
            array ('4','2','2'),
            array ('6','5','2')
        );

        $csv = "Period,Basic Payment,Bonus Payment \n";//Column headers
        foreach ($data_array as $record){
            $csv.= $record[0].','.$record[1].','.$record[2]."\n"; //Append data to csv
        }

        $csv_handler = fopen ('csvfile.csv','w');
        fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
        fclose ($csv_handler);

        echo 'Data saved to csvfile.csv';


    }
}
```

Comment: That's because a one month period you're adding won't fall on the same day. You need to calculate the last working day of each month individually.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, for sure I understand what you are saying. I found this does work individually, but just for a single month

echo date('l', strtotime($lastworkingday))." ".$lastworkingday;

But I'm unsure what code I need to get it to display for 12 months like when I use: echo $lastworkingday->format('t-m-Y') . " | "; as this displays the last working day for each month over 12 months.

Comment: As I said, you calculate the last working day correctly for the first month, but then you just create a date period and expect the following months to also end on a working day. Adding one month to a working day does not move the date forward to the last working day of the next month. You need to create a date period and then apply your working day calculation logic to *every* month in that period.

Comment: Thanks, for sure! However that is what I am stuck with, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Extract the logic that works into a separate method and have it return the last working day. Then iterate the date period you have now and use that method on every date in the loop. You should also have a look at [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), which can help you to easily produce the last day of a month. I would also suggest that you don't start with `31-07-2021`, because adding one month to the last day of a month will end up skipping a month when a shorter month follows.

Comment: I will look into that, thank you!

What I originally wanted was for this line:

$lastdateofthemonth = date("31-07-2021");

(The date I really it want to start with is 01/01/2021) To be removed,  which should have worked, but I ended up with an issue of new \DateTime converted to strtotime error. That was nearst I got to get it to work, but I just couldn't get the dates to convert and work

Comment: Starting with the first day is good. 1) Create date period for 12 months (you already know how to do that); 2) Iterate the period and use relative formats to find the last day of the current iteration month; 3) If it's a saturday or sunday, apply your corrective logic.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by modifying my code

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to apply to all dates within the 12 month range

$start    = new DateTime('01-01-2021');
$start->modify('last weekday first day of next month');
$end      = new DateTime('31-12-2021');
$end->modify('last weekday first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("d-m-Y") . "<br>\n";
}